# How to properly set the kivy button background_disabled_down property?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have looked at the kivy button docs, and it states that baground_disabled_down defaults to ‘atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_disabled_pressed’. so I figured this was a path to the image I want to display, so I put my own path in the kv file, yet nothing shows up.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Theming-Kivy)?

Comment: I had not seen that, thank you. I did however happen to figure out what I was doing wrong. I was trying to set a path to where my image is stored on my pc. the other thing I was doing wrong was trying to set it like you would for an image (background_normal: 'Images\banner.jpg'), and that's partially correct except that the "\" has to be "/". and that works. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the backslash should be a forwardslash.